# How to call an update table that is inside in the procedure for a function in PLSQL?

Tags: function, plsql, procedure

This is my situation:

I have a procedure that do an update table like this:

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_MODEL AS
STR VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN

STR:='UPDATE SAE_MODEL_TABLE.....'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STR;
```

I need to do a function that call this `UPDATE SAE_MODEL_TABLE`...

I tried with this code

```
FUNCTION GET_MODEL_TABLE  RETURN CLOB AS
STR4 VARCHAR2(50);
count_table number;

BEGIN

str4:='select count(1) from SAE_MODEL_TABLE;
execute immediate str4 into count_table;

IF count_table <> 0 then
UPDATE_MODEL ;
```

**I have this error:**

> ORA-14551: DML operation can not be performed within a query,

I know that refers for add an update...

Comment: Why do you use dymamic sql to count rows or update?
In general best practices for functions are not to use DML setences (insert, update, delete).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you use dynamic SQL, but if you really want to do it, it might look like this

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_MODEL AS
  STR VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN

  STR:='UPDATE SAE_MODEL_TABLE.....'
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STR;
end;


FUNCTION GET_MODEL_TABLE  RETURN CLOB AS
  STR4 VARCHAR2(50);
  count_table number;
  my_clob clob;
BEGIN

  str4:='select count(1) from SAE_MODEL_TABLE';
  execute immediate str4 into count_table;

  IF count_table <> 0 then
    UPDATE_MODEL() ;
  end if;

  return my_clob;
end;
```